# If $f(x,y)$ is homogenous of degree $0$, how do $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$ compare to $f_x(x/y,1)$ and $f_y(x/y,1)$?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

> If $f(x,y)$ is homogenous of degree $0$, how do $f_x(x,y)$ and
>   $f_y(x,y)$ compare to $f_x(x/y,1)$ and $f_y(x/y,1)$?

Is it simply just that
$$
f_x(x,y)\vert_{x=x/y,y=1} = f_x(x,y) * 1/y
$$
using the fact that if $f$ is homogenous of degree $0$, then $f_x$ is homogenous of degree $-1$?

Edit: if I run an example though I get that $f_x(x,y)= f_x(x/y,1)$, so perhaps I made a mistake in my derivative above.

Edit 2: by $f_x(x/y,1)$ I mean the derivative of $f(x,y)$ w.r.t $x$, EVALUATED at $(x/y,1)$

Comment: $f_x(x/y,1)$ is ambiguous notation.  It could mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(x/y,1)]$, or it could mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$ with substitutions $x/y$ for $x$ and $1$ for $y$.

Comment: @GEdgar I mean the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f_x(x/y,1)$ is ambiguous notation.  Let $f_1, f_2$ be the two partial derivatives of the function $f$ of two variables.  [Advantage of the notation: it applies regardless of what the names of the two variables are.]

Then $f_x(x/y,1)$ could mean
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[f(x/y,1)] = f_1(x/y,1)\;\frac{1}{y}
\tag1$$
Or it could mean $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$ with substitutions $x/y$ for $x$ and $1$ for $y$.  That is
$$
f_1(x/y,1) .
\tag2$$

> In the line in the OP $f_x(x/y,1) = f_x(x/y,1) * 1/y = f_x(x,y) \frac{1}{y^2}$, the expression $f_x(x/y,1)$ appears twice, once with each of those two meanings.

If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $0$, then $f(x/y,1) = f(x,y)$, so
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) = f_1(x,y)
$$
is equal to $(1)$, not $(2)$.

Comment: I see. Is there a relationship between $f_1(x,y)$ and your equation (2)? . And sorry, I think I asked my question is very poor manner (both in using ambiguous terminology and not stating my question clearly). -- Also, in using the notation $f_1(x/y,1)$ and $f_2(x/y,1)$ how is it clear whether $1$ means $x$ or $y$?

Comment: $f_1(x/y,1)$ means: partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its first variable, then plug in $x/y$ and $1$.  So, for example, compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial u} f(u,v)$ and then plug in $u=x/y, v=1$.

Comment: Sorry, one more clarification. What I was trying to ask in an earlier comment was, when we think of $f(x,y)$ as $f(x/y,1)$, where does $f_2$ show up? Because, as you showed, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = f_1(x/y,1)\frac1y$, and similarly, we can show $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = f_1(x/y,1)(-\frac{x}{y^2})$. **That is, $f_2$ does not show up in any of these expressions**, which has me confused, sorry.

Comment: In $f(x/y,1)$, the variables $x,y$ appear only in the first argument of $f$.  So of course $f_1$ is relevant, but not $f_2$.  Think of $f(u,1)$ as a function of one variable $u$.